# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.surfaceCreated()' on a null object reference

Tags: google-cardboard, android-studio-2.0

I am new to google Cardboard, and trying to implement this [example](http://google-cardboard.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-zoom-image-using-cardboard-app.html). I have included the .aar file properly and found this runtime exception when launched. Please suggest how to resolve this and also suggest where to get  basic startup for google cardboard with demo if possible.

I will be really thankful to you for helping me on this topic.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.surfaceCreated()' on a null object reference
                                                           at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(GLSurfaceView.java:556)
                                                           at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:675)
                                                           at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:202)
                                                           at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2357)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6673)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.vr.sdk.base.Eye;
import com.google.vr.sdk.base.GvrActivity;
import com.google.vr.sdk.base.GvrView;
import com.google.vr.sdk.base.HeadTransform;
import com.google.vr.sdk.base.Viewport;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;

public class MainActivity extends GvrActivity implements
        GvrView.StereoRenderer {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity2";

    Uri fileUri = null;
    ImageView photoImage = null;

    private Vibrator mVibrator;

    private int mScore = 0;

    private CardboardOverlayView mOverlayView;

    public MainActivity() {
    }

    /**
     * Sets the view to our CardboardView and initializes the transformation
     * matrices we will use to render our scene. //@param savedInstanceState
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        GvrView cardboardView = (GvrView) findViewById(R.id.cardboard_view1);

        setGvrView(cardboardView);

        mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        mOverlayView = (CardboardOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.overlay);

        mOverlayView.show3DSplashImage();

        mOverlayView.show3DImage(mScore++, MainActivity.this);
        mVibrator.vibrate(50);


    }

    protected void onNfcIntent(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRendererShutdown() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRendererShutdown");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated");
    }


    /**
     * Creates the buffers we use to store information about the 3D world.
     * OpenGL doesn't use Java arrays, but rather needs data in a format it can
     * understand. Hence we use ByteBuffers.
     *
     * @param config
     *            The EGL configuration used when creating the surface.
     */


    /*@Override
    public void onCardboardTrigger() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRendererShutdown1");

        mOverlayView.show3DImage(mScore++, MainActivity.this);
        mVibrator.vibrate(50);
    }*/

    /**
     * Prepares OpenGL ES before we draw a frame.
     *
     * @param headTransform
     *            The head transformation in the new frame.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {

    }

    /**
     * Draws a frame for an eye. The transformation for that eye (from the
     * camera) is passed in as a parameter.
     *
     * @param viewport
     *            The transformations to apply to render this eye.
     */


    @Override
    public void onFinishFrame(Viewport viewport) {
    }

    public void onRemovedFromCardboard() {
        Log.d("vbv", "msg");
    }
}
```

CardboardOverlayView.java is Linear layout extented class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was missing that

```
GvrView cardboardView = (GvrView) findViewById(R.id.cardboard_view1);

        cardboardView.setRenderer(this);
```

Comment: What about when orientation of device changes? I'm correctly assigning the renderer in OnCreate, but this method is being thrown when device orientation is changed.